# How to disable autohide dock autohide when the app closes

Tags: applescript, dock

I'm not an AppleScript Ninja but so I followed this [link](https://discussions.apple.com/message/30505361?replyId=30505361) to automatically hide dock when it opens Unreal Engine

```
tell application "System Events"
  set autohide of dock preferences to true
end tell
tell application "UE4Editor" to activate
```

But, how to disable autohide when Unreal Engine closes? I'm running this script as an App.

Is there any way I can integrate this script to `Unreal Engine` app? So, I don't have to click on this app manually & everything is done for me behind the scenes automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to worry about creating a ***race condition*** and having to close **UE4Editor** before shutting down, as mentioned in the other answer, then there is a nice app called [**EventScripts**](http://mousedown.net/mouseware/EventScripts.html), for $3.99 USD at the [**App Store**](https://itunes.apple.com/app/eventscripts/id525319418?mt=12), that you can use to *trigger* **AppleScript** *scripts* and or **Shell** *scripts* when [certain](http://mousedown.net/mouseware/Event_Parameters.html) *events* are *triggered*.

Here's an example **AppleScript** *script* that will *hide/show* the **Dock** when **UE4Editor** *launches/quits*:

```
on run eventArgs
    set theAppName to applicationName in eventArgs
    set theTrigger to trigger in eventArgs
    if theTrigger is "Application launched" and theAppName is "UE4Editor" then
        hideDock(true)
    else if theTrigger is "Application quit" and theAppName is "UE4Editor" then
        hideDock(false)
    end if
end run

on hideDock(b)
    tell application "System Events"
        set autohide of dock preferences to b
    end tell
end hideDock
```

In **Script Editor**, save the above **AppleScript** *code* as, e.g., **UE4Editor - On Open and Close.scpt** in **~/Library/Application Scripts/net.mousedown.EventScripts/**, (after EventScripts is installed).

Now in **EventScripts**, add the same *script* twice, while setting the **Event** for *one* to **Application launched** and the *other* to **Application quit**.

Now, when **UE4Editor** launches, the **Dock** is hidden, and when **UE4Editor** quits the **Dock** is unhidden.

[image: EventScripts]

**EventScripts** has a long list of *events* it can *trigger* a script on. Check out the links below for more information:

- EventScripts - [Developers Website](http://mousedown.net/mouseware/EventScripts.html)
- EventScripts - [Mac App Store Preview](https://itunes.apple.com/app/eventscripts/id525319418?mt=12)
- EventScripts - [Available Events and Parameters](http://mousedown.net/mouseware/Event_Parameters.html)
- EventScripts - [Example Scripts](http://mousedown.net/mouseware/Event_Examples.html)

Note: I'm not affiliated with the developer of EventScripts, just a satisfied customer.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on whether UE4Editor will launch from shell script, so I cannot test it... it works fine with TextEdit.

Save this as a standalone app, rather than a script. It should work as either, but an app is tidier.

```
tell application "System Events" to set autohide of dock preferences to true
tell current application to do shell script "/Applications/UE4Editor.app/Contents/MacOS/UE4Editor"  
tell application "System Events" to set autohide of dock preferences to false
```

As you are launching from shell script, the script app will hide the Dock, launch your editor, then simply wait until the UE4Editor quits, then continue from where it left off, hiding the Dock. It will then quit itself.
This does mean that it will look like it went Not Responding for the duration of your session, but that actually causes no issues in itself. I have script apps like this that sit open for a week or more & do no harm at all.

*Note:* If you reboot the Mac whilst this is running, the Mac itself will restore your last Editor session & therefore will be in a race condition with the script. Make sure to quit the editor before shutting down or rebooting.